# BSOD 0x124 Help needed

Tags: windows-8, drivers, crash, bsod, machine-check-exception

I have a new Computer for 3 weeks now and I get a lot of WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR BSODs. I get these bluescreens randomly every 30 - 50 minutes.

Here is the dump from WinDbg:

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.2.9200.20512 AMD64 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Loading Dump File [C:\Windows\Minidump\050913-7984-01.dmp] Mini Kernel Dump File: Only registers and stack trace are available

Symbol search path is: SRV*c:\Symbole*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols Executable search path is: Windows 8 Kernel Version 9200 MP (4 procs) Free x64 Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS Built by: 9200.16551.amd64fre.win8_gdr.130306-1502 Machine Name: Kernel base = 0xfffff80104018000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff801042e4b00 Debug session time: Thu May 9 17:12:45.597 2013 (UTC + 2:00) System Uptime: 0 days 0:00:25.246 Loading Kernel Symbols ............................................................... ................................................................ .................. Loading User Symbols Loading unloaded module list .......

* Bugcheck Analysis * * Use !analyze -v to get detailed debugging information.

BugCheck 124, {0, fffffa8008c87028, be200000, 2110a}

Probably caused by : GenuineIntel

Followup: MachineOwner

1: kd> !analyze -v

* Bugcheck Analysis * * WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR (124) A fatal hardware error has occurred. Parameter 1 identifies the type of error source that reported the error. Parameter 2 holds the address of the WHEA_ERROR_RECORD structure that describes the error conditon. Arguments: Arg1: 0000000000000000, Machine Check Exception Arg2: fffffa8008c87028, Address of the WHEA_ERROR_RECORD structure. Arg3: 00000000be200000, High order 32-bits of the MCi_STATUS value. Arg4: 000000000002110a, Low order 32-bits of the MCi_STATUS value.

Debugging Details:

BUGCHECK_STR: 0x124_GenuineIntel
CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT: 1
DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID: WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT
PROCESS_NAME: System
CURRENT_IRQL: f
STACK_TEXT: fffff880009f9868 fffff8010479193d : 0000000000000124 0000000000000000 fffffa8008c87028 00000000be200000 : nt!KeBugCheckEx fffff880009f9870 fffff80104178969 : 0000000000000001 fffffa80066d7320 0000000000000000 fffffa8008c87028 : hal!HalBugCheckSystem+0xf9 fffff880009f98b0 fffff801047916e3 : 0000000000000728 0000000000000001 fffff880009f9a10 fffffa80066d7320 : nt!WheaReportHwError+0x249 fffff880009f9910 fffff8010479100c : 0000000000000010 fffffa80066d7320 fffff880009f9ac8 fffffa80066d7320 : hal!HalpMcaReportError+0x53 fffff880009f9a70 fffff80104790f07 : fffffa800678b760 0000000000000001 0000000000000001 0000000000000000 : hal!HalpMceHandlerCore+0xd4 fffff880009f9ac0 fffff80104790d64 : 0000000000000004 0000000000000001 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 : hal!HalpMceHandler+0xe3 fffff880009f9b00 fffff80104791edb : fffffa800678b760 fffff880009f9d30 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 : hal!HalpMceHandlerWithRendezvous+0xd4 fffff880009f9b30 fffff8010407057b : 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 : hal!HalHandleMcheck+0x40 fffff880009f9b60 fffff8010407032e : 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 : nt!KxMcheckAbort+0x7b fffff880009f9ca0 fffff8800158e984 : 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 : nt!KiMcheckAbort+0x16e fffff88002e1b888 0000000000000000 : 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 : intelppm!MWaitIdle+0x18
STACK_COMMAND: kb
FOLLOWUP_NAME: MachineOwner
MODULE_NAME: GenuineIntel
IMAGE_NAME: GenuineIntel
DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP: 0
FAILURE_BUCKET_ID: 0x124_GenuineIntel_PROCESSOR_CACHE
BUCKET_ID: 0x124_GenuineIntel_PROCESSOR_CACHE
Followup: MachineOwner
```

I have also reinstalled Windows 3 times now but every time I get these errors. Can anyone tell me whats the problem is?

Comment: You either have defective hardware or this is a driver problem. Based on the Microsoft support articles on this error code, its either drivers or your HDD to blame. I would start by making sure every single one of your devices have the current drivers. If that doesn't work and this is actually a "new" computer I would RMA it.  **Even an 5 year old computer shouldn't get BSDO errors like this.**

Comment: `A fatal hardware error has occurred`

Comment: Check your event log, look for any disk errors that show a bad block. If found, run a chkdsk /f.  but since you said this is a new computer i would get it replaced under warranty.

Comment: type `!errrec fffffa8008c87028` and post the new output